# Convert Xaml to Baml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is there a way to convert xaml to Baml.  I have no source code and need to make a small change to an application that is no longer supported. I have the xaml file and can make the changes but I need to get it back to Baml format. I can save the raw baml file and open in notepad++ but it's unreadable. I can change dates and colours in the unreadable baml file save it and it works. So I need a baml editor or converter for xaml to Baml

Comment: Try using Reflexil -- http://reflexil.net -- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20565/Assembly-Manipulation-and-C-VB-NET-Code-Injection

Answer (score 0):

`BAML` is just compiled `XAML` file, so I would imagine that you could simply compile the `XAML` file to get the appropriate `BAML` code.

If you have access to [Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx), you could likely create a project containing your single `XAML` file(s) and building/compiling it, which should generate the appropriate `BAML` file(s). [This related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1714036/557445) details the process.

Additionally, a tool like [this XAML Code Behind Generator](http://xamlgenerator.codeplex.com/) might be of some use to you as well. While it may not generate the appropriate `BAML`, it could give you a bit more information about the project/source in general.